# How to check if object behind pointer is valid or was deleted?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have two manager-classes `ManagerA`and `ManagerB`. Both of them hold a `std::vector` of pointers, that point to some objects. The problem is that a pointer from `ManagerA` can point to the same object `obj` like a pointer from `ManagerB`. Now, if I delete the `obj` from the vector of `ManagerA`, the program will crash, because `ManagerB` tries to access the object `obj` which is invalid now.

```
class ManagerA
{
public:
  std::vector<Object*> listA;
}

class ManagerB
{
public:
  std::vector<Object*> listB;
}

int main()
{
  ManagerA* A = new ManagerA();
  ManagerB* B = new ManagerB();
  Object* O = new Object();

  A->listA.push_back(O);
  B->listB.push_back(O);

  delete A.listA[0];
  B->listB[0]->doStuff(); // will crash here! How to avoid?

  retrun 0;
}
```

How can I avoid this? Is there a way to check in `ManagerB`, that the object, that is adressed by a pointer in `listB` is now invalid?

Comment: `std::shared_ptr`, `std::make_shared`, and `std::weak_ptr` can help in these kinds of situations.

Comment: Short answer: you cannot determine this with raw pointers.

Comment: The main way to avoid these problems is to not use pointers in the first place. There's no reason for any of those pointers in the code above.

Comment: @Eljay Smart pointers can certainly help, and should be preferred, but they can't guarantee what the OP is asking about.

Comment: Post code that you have tried with compiler.

Comment: @john We don't know that. The manager classes may need to share objects and neither own them, for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raw pointers themselves have no way of communicating to their owner(s) that they are being deleted.  You'd need to add that into your code such that every place that may participate in shared ownership verifies if it is the last owner, and if so, then does the `delete`.

Alternatively, you could express the shared ownership using `std::shared_ptr` of the Object.  The `shared_ptr` will manage the joint ownership of the object.

Additionally, if some things need a `weak_ptr` it also provides that facility.  A "weak pointer" is a pointer to the object that is aware when the object has been destructed.  Objects get destructed when there are no `std::shared_ptr` "strong pointers" to the object left.

Sometimes the Object needs to be self-aware that it is owned by a `shared_ptr`, and that is where inheriting from `std::enable_shared_from_this` is useful.  (Personally, I think of `std::enable_shared_from_this` as being a bad pattern.  But it is right in the standard.  Just be careful about not making such things on the stack or merely `new`ing them up because then they aren't shared_ptr but the instance object doesn't know how it was created.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::make_shared;
using std::shared_ptr;

struct Object final {
    unsigned int amIAlive = 0x600D600D;
    ~Object() { amIAlive = 0xDEADDEAD; }
    void doStuff() const;
};

void Object::doStuff() const {
    if (amIAlive == 0x600D600D) {
        cout << "Object is GOOD GOOD!\n";
    } else if (amIAlive == 0xDEADDEAD) {
        cout << "Object is DEAD DEAD and gone. Probably going to crash soon.\n";
    } else {
        cout << "Object is gone and overwritten. Probably going to crash soon.\n";
    }
}

class ManagerA final {
    vector<shared_ptr<Object>> listA;
public:
    void push_back(shared_ptr<Object> o) {
        listA.push_back(o);
    }
    void erase_at(size_t pos) {
        if (pos >= listA.size()) return; // No-op? throw?
        auto offset = static_cast<decltype(listA)::difference_type>(pos);
        listA.erase(listA.begin() + offset);
    }
};

class ManagerB final {
    vector<shared_ptr<Object>> listB;
public:
    void push_back(shared_ptr<Object> o) {
        listB.push_back(o);
    }
    void do_stuff_at(size_t pos) {
        if (pos >= listB.size()) return; // No-op? throw?
        listB[pos]->doStuff();
    }
};

int main() {
    auto A = ManagerA();
    auto B = ManagerB();
    auto O = make_shared<Object>();

    A.push_back(O);
    B.push_back(O);

    A.erase_at(0);
    B.do_stuff_at(0); // no more crash!
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to check in ManagerB, that the object, that is adressed by a pointer in listB is now invalid?

No.

> How can I avoid this?

You will need to somehow track the validity/existence of the objects in some way.

There are many ways and design patterns to achieve this, depending on your needs.

If you want a generic solution, you may use shared ownership, for instance in the form of a reference-counted pointer, i.e. one that tracks how many people is pointing to the object, like [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) in the standard library. This will give you basically what you get from other languages with a garbage collector.

However, note that it is usually a code smell going for shared ownership unless you have determined that there is no other better option.

Comment: +1 apart from shared ownership being "*usually a code smell*". It's not. It is frequently misused as a lazy unique ownership (since beginners are not fond of `std::move`ing and passing by reference everywhere) where it introduces unnecessary overhead and design flaw, but it certainly is not a code smell.

Comment: @Fureeish A lazy approach to a problem that can be done in a better way is a code smell. There are only very few instances where shared ownership is required. Unless justified properly in comments, a `std::shared_ptr` out of nowhere it is a code smell in my book.

Comment: Not unless the pattern is actually quite widely used. That's my opinion, though. Generally I would agree, but I believe this can't be said for a `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Fureeish How much a pattern is used is not what makes it (or not) a code smell, though. Why wouldn't you say it about `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: Since it is a well-thought tool with clear intentions and it has clear and easy applications. It does not have to be a *special case* to use it - rare or not. That's what, in my opinion, disqualifies `std::shared_ptr` as a code smell.

Comment: Shared ownership is not meant for clear and easy applications, whether you use `std::shared_ptr` or something else. Note that, in the case of `std::shared_ptr`, it is even more pronounced, because it is designed to allow sharing objects between multiple threads. I think (correct me if I am wrong) that you feel that since `std::shared_ptr` it is in the standard library it is to be easily and widely used.

Comment: I'm correcting you since you are wrong, but this is not a place for such discussions. We even triggered the bot :)